# Subset Product has a pseudo-polynomial algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

Subset Product- Given $N$ and a list of positive divisors $S$, decide if there is a product combination equal to $N$

- We will sort $S$ in numerical order from smallest to largest in order
  to find out the maximum combination size to avoid redundancy.
- We will remove non-divisors in $S$. This does not impact the
  correctness, as no possible combination could yield N if there's a
  non-divisor in that combination.

Iterate over divisors of $N$ in $S$ and calculate the maximum combination size. We multiply each divisor in $S$ until the product $<=$ $N$

Isn't the sum of the prime exponents the bound for this?

$O(2^{\text{$Max-combination-size$}})$

We only allow one duplicate of 1 in S (any product combination of 1 is always 1) , to prevent redundant combinations and we sort S from smallest to largest which is a requirement to get $Max-combination-size$. $Max-combination-size$ basically ensures we don't do redundant combinations that will always yield a product > $N$.  So the algorithm runs in $ O(N^M)$ is substantially smaller in magnitude compared to N.

So, we got an efficient algorithm in the value of N??

So there is a pseudo-polynomial algorithm, I just wanted to know if this is always the case if we look at number theorems when it comes to divisors and the value of N?

Comment: The number of divisors of $n$, $d(n)$ isn't $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$. If I remember correctly, it's $\Theta(e^{\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}})$. Anyways, the subset-product problem has a very obvious pseudo-polynomial algorithm via dynamic programming (the algorithm is essentially the same as the simple dynamic programming solution to the subset-sum problem). I'm not sure what you are asking in your last sentence.

Comment: @SharpEdged At worse, I thought it was sqrt(N), but I realized the sum of the exponents of primes could be what M is doing for the maximum combination size. I think that's logarithmic at least on average.

Comment: Is there an infinite number of positive integers for which the sum of the prime exponents in their prime factorization significantly exceeds the logarithm of N??  Looking for those non-trivial inputs would  be very important for my research hobby.

Comment: Do powers of primes only have n divisors for $prime^n$? If so, that's a trivial input. Just get total product of S. Edit: Or n+1??

Comment: You should probably check the wikipedia page of the divisor function, there is a bound of it there. It is $o(n^\varepsilon)$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$.


Yes, if you terminate your algorithm early the maximum size of a combination will be $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$, but that doesn't mean that there will be $\mathcal{O}(2^{\mathcal{O}(\log n)})$ such combinations - as there are $d(n)$ things to pick from, not $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$.

Comment: Still, I don't see the point of your algorithm as the trivial dynamic programming runs in $\mathcal{O}(|S| \cdot n) = \mathcal{O}(n^{1 + \varepsilon})$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$ - much better than you could ever expect your algorithm to run.

Comment: @SharpEdged It would still be more practical "a lot" of larger instances when it comes due to space complexity?  Its in the value of N, even in S? Edit: There must be a bound for S. The combinations are still bounded by the max_comb_size, not S.

Comment: There is a simple modification which will make the dynamic programming approach use $\mathcal{O}(d(n))$ memory - which should be comparable to the memory usage of your algorithm. This modification will also make the running time $\mathcal{O}((d(n))^2)$, which is quite interesting as it's faster than pseudo-polynomial time. I'm honestly not sure how to prove that your algorithm is pseudo-polynomial, I might try again later.